# Closed expression of the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I believe that the following integral has a closed expression, but I haven't been able to check it

$$I(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{b}-i \frac{1}{2}b(k+a)\right) e^{-\frac{t^2}{b^2}-\frac{1}{4}b^2(k+a)^2-i t(k-a)}$$

where $a,\,b$ are real numbers.

Could you give me some advice on how to proceed, or simply the result?

Comment: What is the basis for your belief?

Comment: I have edited the expression to help me with the explanation. Basically, I know that $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } T}{8\pi^2}\int_0^\infty dk \sin{k}( e^{-i t (k-a )-\frac{1}{4} T^2 (k+a )^2-\frac{t^2}{T^2}}+I(k))=-\frac{Te^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2T^2+\frac{1}{T^2}\right)} \left(\text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}T}\right)-i\right)}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi } }$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was working in @Lucian's hint when I realized there is no need to "forget to derive" the exponential part. Let me do it step by step

1. We derive $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$
   $$I'(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\,\left(2 i a e^{-a^2-i b t-t^2} \text{erfi}(a+i t)-\frac{2 i e^{-a^2+(a+i t)^2-i b t-t^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)\\
   =-2a\,I(a)-i \sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{1}{8} (b-2 a)^2}.$$
2. We solve the homogenous differential equation and obtain $I_H(a)=Ce^{-a^2}$.
3. Using variation of constants we get:
   $$C'(a)e^{-a^2}=-i\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{1}{8}\left(b-2a\right)^2}\\
   C(a)=-i \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{b^2}{4}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{2 a+b}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$
   So the final solution is
   $$I(a)=-i\sqrt{\pi}e^{-a^2-\frac{b^2}{4}}\text{erfi}\left(\frac{a+\frac{b}{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
   Which is Lucian's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\text{erf}\big(t-ia\big)}{\exp\big(A^2+Bi~t+t^2\big)}~dt,~$ and [evaluate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) $I'(a)$, then [integrate back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

with regard to *a*, and let $A=a$ and $B=2\beta$. You'll get $I(a)=-i~\sqrt\pi~\dfrac{\text{erfi}\bigg(\dfrac{a+\beta}{\sqrt2}\bigg)}{\exp\big(a^2+\beta^2\big)}~.$

Comment: Computer-aided numerical evaluations of the two expressions for various values of *a* and *b* confirm the identity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am not totally convinced that one can first derive w.r.t. `a` and then make the substitution `A=a` without having derived that contribution previously.

Comment: @pepeperez: I had that same doubt, which is why I verified the result.

Comment: would you then mind elaborating a bit on how did you verified the result? It doesn't appear being obvious to me what to do.

Comment: @pepeperez: As I said, I evaluated both expressions numerically for various values of the parameters, to make sure that the theory fits the facts.

Comment: Just checked numerically as you did, and indeed works. Thank you very much, I will keep working on the explanation of your Hint